# Submit all data at once instead of iterating though a list

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using AJAX to submit data to a script that will update my db.

Normally this is pretty straight-forward, but in this case when I click submit button, I need to iterate through a list of selectors to collect values. I can do it this way, but it seems it makes more sense to collect the data together into some sort of an array and then post it just once.

```
 $(document).on('click', '#submit', function(){

        $('.myForm').each(function() {
            var hid = $(this).closest('.myForm').attr('data-hid'),
                opn = $(this).find('.tOpen'),
                cls = $(this).find('.tClose'),
                old_opn = opn.attr('data-open'),
                new_opn = opn.val()+':00',
                old_cls = cls.attr('data-close'),
                new_cls = cls.val()+':00';

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:  '/myscript.ajax',
                data: {
                    'hid' : bid,
                    'old_opn' : old_opn,
                    'new_opn' : new_opn,
                    'old_cls' : old_cls,
                    'new_cls' : new_cls

                },
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    // done
                }
            });
        });            
    });
```

I feel like I'm pretty close but still need a bit of help sorting this out.

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question extract that data beforehand and send it all in one go because you definitely shouldn't be making an ajax request for each iteration

Comment: So, I need to build some sort of an array in JS and then send it over and iterate on the AJAX script's side?

Comment: yes, just plan out how you want to store your data and send it over and de-structure it on the server, this way you also ensure that all data gets sent over whereas if you loop over requests what if one of them fails?

Comment: `$(this).closest(".myForm")` doesn't make sense. `this` is  `.myForm`

Comment: Do you really have multiple forms, or is it one form with multiple rows of data? Have you looked at `.serializeArray()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
let allData = [];

$('.myForm').each(function() {
  var tempArray = [];
  tempArray['hid'] = $(this).closest('.myForm').attr('data-hid');
  tempArray['opn'] = opn = $(this).find('.tOpen');
  tempArray['cls'] = $(this).find('.tClose');
  tempArray['old_opn'] = opn.attr('data-open');
  tempArray['new_opn'] = opn.val()+':00';
  tempArray['old_cls'] = cls.attr('data-close');
  tempArray['new_cls'] = cls.val()+':00';

  allData.push(tempArray)
});
```

And then send all over in one go